# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found Type Status Report Message on running the Apache Tomcat Server on STS for index.html page

Tags: java, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-wtp, tomcat8.5

[This is the Image it shows when i run a basic index.html file in my dynamic web project on Spring Tool Suite 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWkSi.png)

I've tried deleting the current Tomcat server and creating the new servers. All the configurations are also properly set, but I don't know where the error exists!
Please help[.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - and also: Please read [ask]: All you state is that everything is right - but apparently it isn't. Without a [mcve], we can't tell you either...

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer server.xml file and based on that configuration try with that port number.